# windows form open embeded window (userControl/Windows Form) when pressing a button

Tags: c#, forms, winforms, user-controls, mdi

I am developing a generic GUI with a windows form in c#.

I have added different buttons and windows on the right panel of the form. What I would like to do is to link these buttons on the right with different subforms (?) which will appear on the left. In particular, when pressing a button on the right panel, I would like to display a new form/userControl/window/or-anything-you-recommend on the left panel of my ParentForm. Should I go with MDI Form? How could I specify where to position each of the child forms on the Parent one?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: It depends on your requirements. You can use a multi-tab or multi-page UI and host user controls or forms in the tabs/pages. To host a user control or a form in the tab, it's enough to set it's dock property to fill.

Comment: Hi Reza, I think that the multi-page UI is more siutable to my requirements. Many thanks for your suggestions.